# Image upload doesn't work in mozilla and Internet Explorer - asks to save files

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have implemented upload feature in ASP.MVC. I am using `jQuery.BlockUI` and `JQuery.Form` plugins (but I don't know is this important). And everything works perfect in Google Chrome.

But in Mozilla and Internet Explorer it doesn't. When I try to upload image it asks me in popup window:

> Upload. You have chosen to open Upload which is a: application/json
>   from http://localhost:2993 What should Firefox do with this file?

And I have open with/save and browse options.

In my upload method I am returning JSon here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload()
{
   string savedFileName = null;
   string hName = null;
   for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
   {
      HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[i] as HttpPostedFileBase;
      if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
         continue;

      string savedFileNameThumb = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                   "Content", "Images", "Thumb",
                   Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));

      savedFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                   "Content", "Images", "Full",
                   Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
      hName = hpf.FileName;

      ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(savedFileName, hpf.FileName, hpf.InputStream, int.MaxValue, false);
      // for cropping
      ImageModel.ResizeAndSave(savedFileName, hpf.FileName, hpf.InputStream, 540, false);
   }

   string r = string.Format("../../Content/Images/Full/{0}", hName);
   return Json(new { foo = r });
}
```

What produce this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning JSON as the page to the user following the upload. The JSON won't make any sense to a regular user, so most browsers doesn't have any predefined way to display the JSON.

If the returned page is displayed somewhere, you should return a regular HTML page that means something to the user. If the page isn't really displayed somewhere (e.g. loaded in a hidden frame), you should return an empty HTML page that all browsers know how to display.

Comment: @1110: The result will be handled as a page by the browser, so it has to be a page. If you need to return any information, you have to put that in the page, either in a script that runs when the page is loaded, or in an element that you can access from another script.

Comment: Really? This is an answer? I can think of a bazillion reasons why you'd want to have your upload script return json. The most obvious reason is that you've done an asynchronous file upload in js and you don't want to navigate away from your current page/application. The bug here is that the browser is not expecting json because of how the request/response is setup and therefore tries to open it instead of just using the data in js.

Comment: @FlavorScape: Badmouthing other answers is not really polite.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the actual fix. In the case that you're doing an asynchronous iframe upload (which is the standard AJAX way of uploading files in the background) you have to set the response type on the server side to "text/html" not "text/json"

http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-120201.html